# Shorthand to invoke function on each item with '_.some'

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am using the lodash method **`_.some`**.

For the predicate, I am just calling a method on the current item and returning the value.

```
return _.some(items, function(item) {
    return item.hasChanges();
});
```

This works as expected!

However, I am wondering if there is a shorthand way of performing this operation?

If `hasChanges` were a property, I could do:

```
return _.some(items, "hasChanges");
```

I tried to invoke the method via:

```
return _.some(items, _.invoke(_.identity, "hasChanges"));
```

But it did not seem to work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to go the Lodash way, you could use [`_.partial`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partial) and [`_.result`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#result) or [`_.invoke`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#invoke) to build the equivalent of your custom predicate.

```
_.some(users, _.partial(_.invoke, _, 'hasChanges'));
```

The predicate could be created once and used later:

```
var predicate = _.partial(_.invoke, _, 'hasChanges');
// later...
// a function which only checks, without creating a
// new anonymous function each time.
function check() {
    return _.some(users, predicate);
}
```

ES6 using Array's `some` function and an arrow function.

```
items.some(item => item.hasChanged());
```

`_.some` (or most `some` function implementation) break the looping at the first truthy occurrence. A function like `_.invokeMap` will call the function on every object regardless of the result **which is less efficient than the custom predicate we already have**.

[Lodash offers shorthand syntax for common predicates](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#some), but they don't call functions on objects.

> ```
> // The `_.matches` iteratee shorthand.
> _.some(users, { 'user': 'barney', 'active': false });
> // => false
>
> // The `_.matchesProperty` iteratee shorthand.
> _.some(users, ['active', false]);
> // => true
>
> // The `_.property` iteratee shorthand.
> _.some(users, 'active');
> // => true
> ```

---

The following won't work:

```
_.invoke(_.identity, "hasChanges")
```

It's similar to `_.identity.hasChanges()`.

Comment: Great info! 

The ES6 syntax seems like the most concise method for sure. 

Thanks for clearing up why the plain _.invoke didn't work, as well as reminding me that _.identity and the placeholder _ are completely different!